# Insert json object in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I am developing a small application in JSP.

My idea is to give reference to a JSON element while user is typing in the text area.

for example:
If my JSON contains:

cO2,
H2O,
c9O

and in the text area the user is typing a sentence and as soon as the user types a special character such as @ or \ or / if he/she writes "c" character I want a small drop down to appear with the two elements starting with c.
The user can select the element afterwards and then when the form is posted I want to extract those information which was entered from JSON.

This is like when you start typing a name in Facebook I guess.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adhly/mqxv8vn3/22/)

```
<form action="./Protocol" method="POST">
    <textarea rows=5 cols=50></textarea>
   <input type="submit"/></form>
```

```
$('textarea').textcomplete([{
match: /(^|\s)(\w{2,})$/,
search: function (term, callback) {
    var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'github', 'microsoft', 'yahoo'];
    callback($.map(words, function (word) {
        return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
},
replace: function (word) {
    return word + ' ';
}}]);
```

The above JS Fiddle does what I want partly.

One of the two things I want to accomplish here
1. if in the JSON, each word has an ID like `{"ID": "1","name": "GOOGLE"}` can I get the IDs that are in the textarea to be posted when the form is posted
2. or just the array index numbers, how do I POST the values in the form separately from the textarea.

Comment: I have seen that before try using at.js I guess this is what you want [http://ichord.github.io/At.js/](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/)

Comment: You don't mean "JSON element". You basically want an array of those terms and a function to filter out those ones that match the input.

Comment: You should also add the code you've attempted so far. We can help you with mistakes or errors but we don't really code everything for you.

Comment: `any ideas` is not a proper question when all you have provided is a broad concept and no actual code

Comment: This is way too broad.

Comment: Thanks JoyBlanks, this looks like the one I want, I will try and update here, sorry my question was broad, I did not start coding yet, I just wanted to see if anyone else tried it and couldn't find similar thing on the forum. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, despite what I said, here's a basic example of how you might achieve this (because I was bored, but not so bored I'm going to do it all for you :)):

HTML

```
<input id="input"/>
<div id="dropdown"></div>
```

JS

```
// grab the DOM elements
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

// assign an function to the onkeyup event for your input box
input.onkeyup = search;

// define your data structure
var arr = ['cO2', 'H2O', 'c9O'];

function search() {

  // get the content and length of the content
  // `this` in this instance refers to the element to which
  // we assigned the function
  var val = this.value;
  var len = val.length;

  // filter out the elements from the array that match
  // the content, or nothing if the input is empty
  dropdown.textContent = arr.filter(function(el) {
    return val !=='' ? el.substring(0, len) === val : '';
  });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pworhqyg/3/)

Hope that helps you on your way.

Comment: Ok thanks for the code Andy, What if it was a textarea `<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div id="dropdown"></div>` and along the text area while I am typing a sentence and I type 'c' the prompt comes up.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, sorry.

Comment: I have edited with code and JS Fiddle